# JavaScript up and down Arrow menu (Only Javascript)

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

**Javascript up and Down Arrow menu**

Here I posted my code please, I wanna create some javascript arrow for the menu which is functions need up and down, so I tried to figure out it's only having in jquery I search everywhere there are so many confusing codes are out there. But i need a simple and pure javascript code only. please someone willing to help me.

```js
var menuup = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-down");
var menudwn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-open');
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px 0px 0px 180px;
  width: 1rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

nav ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.9rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #339999;
}

.btn-open:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0de";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.btn-down:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0dd";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <nav>  
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="btn-down">About us</a></li>                                           
      </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Simplicity is relative, and overrated(?). Where have you stuck in your current implementation? I mean you say you "_need a simple and pure javascript code_", but I can't see any JS code related to the "arrow menu" in the question at all. Oh no, please don't say you want us to write all the code you need ...

Comment: Also the requirement is not clear at all

Comment: You need to add event listeners to your buttons.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  Also if you are wanting a single up or down button, you will either need to take the first element in the collection that you are finding with `getElementsByClassName` or take a more specific approach and move to using id

Comment: Ok, I will Try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
var anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

anchors.map(anchor => {
 if(anchor.classList.contains('btn-open') || anchor.classList.contains('btn-down')) {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(anchor.classList.contains('btn-open')) {
        anchor.classList.remove('btn-open');
        anchor.classList.add('btn-down');
      } else {
        anchor.classList.add('btn-open');
        anchor.classList.remove('btn-down');
      } 
    });
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px 0px 0px 180px;
  width: 1rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

nav ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.9rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #339999;
}

.btn-open:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0de";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 8px;
}

.btn-down:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0dd";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn-down">About us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn-down">Products</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. This What have been looking for it.

Comment: But, Why its not work Another menu arrow function. Here is i have example in the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/1323/

Comment: @sai Because `anchor = document.querySelector('a')`.

Comment: Can you tell me How do i use multiple arrow menu function? i tried math function its not work. Should i give document.getelement? instead of document.querySelector

Comment: Extended discussion in comments is discouraged. [Let's continue the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181666/javascript)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/1351/  

When i click the product its arrow coming ? its coming all menus i need only dropdown areas ?  How to reslove it ?

Comment: Add an *if-condition* before adding event listeners to your anchors - `if(anchor.classList.contains('btn-open') || anchor.classList.contains('btn-down'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181718/discussion-between-sai-and-rv7).